# Alterar classe do label para active após requisição http angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, material-design

Tenho um componente do material design bootstrap que depois de uma requisição http ele é preenchido, o problema é que ele não altera para a classe "active", tendo o resultado da foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
          <div class="md-form form-lg">
            <input type="text" id="form2" value="{{cliente.whatsapp}}" class="form-control">
            <label for="form2">Whatsapp</label>
          </div>
```

Se eu tentar trocar a label class="active", eu ainda não consigo o resultado da label no topo, como posso corrigir isso?

`<label class="active" for="form2">Whatsapp</label>` não funciona

Devo aplicar a classe active quando tiver valor no input.

Answer (score 0):

Voce poderia usar o [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

ele tem a seguinte sintaxe `ngClass="{classe: condicao}"`

```
<div class="md-form form-lg">
            <input [ngClass]="{active: cliente.whatsapp}" type="text" id="form2" value="{{cliente.whatsapp}}" class="form-control">
            <label for="form2">Whatsapp</label>
</div>
```